# Checked Id Doesn't retrieve from a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

i have a grid as

```
 <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="20px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkSelect" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LbLId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="20%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

i want to retrieve the `ID` of a Checkbox which is checked. I have tried implementing this code, as

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GvDDlToken.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chk = row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
                if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
                {

                        string id = "," + row.Cells[1].Text;


                }
            }
```

but at `Checkbox chk` the value comes as null, no object reference has been made. what possible error i am doing? Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) 
**sample :**

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GvDDlToken.Rows)
{
    if(((CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked == true)
    {
    //some code
    }
}
```